# Why my launchSettings.json settings get ignored?

Tags: identityserver4

I just got IdentityServer to run on my Windows 10 from qickstart VS.Net 2019 project. In my launchSettings.json file, I configured it to run HTTPS on port 5008, instead of the default 5001, as shown bellow:

```
{     
  "profiles": {
    "SelfHost": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5008"
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is, when I start IdentityServer using SelfHost profile, it still starts on HTTPS:5001 and my settings are always get ignored, as the console screen shows below:

…

[14:16:04 Information] Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000

[14:16:04 Information] Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime
Now listening on: https://localhost:5001

…

What am I doing wrong here? Isn't launchSetting.json the place you can change those settings?

Comment: As I noticed later, the configuration info that I put into launchSettings.jon doesn't seem to matter at all. Whatever I change it to, all get ignored. The server always start on HTTP(port 5000) and HTTPS(port5001). How do I change these default settings? What am I missing here?

Comment: not sure if it has any thing to do with IdentityServer, but to verify, can u share gh link to ur code? In the meantime here is a good ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1#development-and-launchsettingsjson

Comment: Thank you nahidf for pointing me to the doc. It's really helpful! And please excuse my ignorance - as you can see, I am completely new to both IdentityServer and .net core - what is "gh link"? Thanks again.

Comment: No worries! I meant link to your code on Github. or if u have any other preferred method to share code do so

Comment: Oh, sorry, we are using our internal AZDO for source control, not GitHub. But I really don't have any custom code except the modified launchSettings.json file. Other than that, the entire solution are built by getting code and following instructions from the quickstart site.

Comment: I just got the code on https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/main/samples/Quickstarts/6_AspNetIdentity and verified on my machine, it works with custom https and http port. Can you verify this as well? only other thing I can think of is `dev https certificate for ASP.NET Core`, I'll leave you the instruction in the answer for you @alexu

Comment: I didn't get code from Github and maybe that's what I should try. What I did was just by following IdentityServer4 quickstart doc step by step and run those dotnet new commends. But they should be the same aren't they?

Comment: Yeah should be the same, but you might have made some tiny mistakes. Thats why I asked you to share ur code with me. try getting the code from github

Comment: Never used Github before, but when I am on it by following your link, I couldn't figure out how to download the code - there is no download button or link to click on... I am really sorry about my ignorance on this platform!

Answer (score 0):

To develop locally with ASP.NET Core under HTTPS, SSL, and Self-Signed Certs, follow these steps:

- Install the certificate on the machine, by running in cmd:

```
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

- Copy localhost Certificate thumbprint
- Then run in cmd for each URL:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\IisExpressAdminCmd.exe" setupSslUrl -url:https://my.domain.name:<port> -CertHash:<Certificate thumbprint>
```

I have these instruction with snapshots [here](https://github.com/nahidf/auth0-adventures#local-https-with-aspnet-core)

Comment: thank you nahidf for the input, but my problem isn't just about HTTPS. HTTP has the same issue as well. I am currently ok with a workaround in my code. I can reach my server using HTTPS:5008 now, which means I must have the certificate in place already.

Comment: From Main method, when calling CreateHostBuilder(string[] args), I am doing:
                webBuilder.UseUrls("https://localhost:5008/"). Again, I consider this a workaround, not a solution. But it works for me.

Comment: Did you ever figure out why your launchSettings were being ignored? A developer on my team is having the same issue when all other devs are running under the configured port.